# is it possible to change the size of audio player in html5 in new tab

Tags: html5-video

Is it possible to change the size of audio player in html5 in new tab?
[image]

Comment: Best approach is create and customize your own control bar. Deafult bar style depends of target browser. You could change some like your <video></video> style by JS. For example with jQuery: `$('video').css('width', '100%');` it changes bar width but also changes vídeo width.

Comment: it is a pity, thx